how to prove Bernstein polynomials proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem on $L^1 ([0,1])$
how to prove Bernstein polynomials proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem on $L^1 ([0,1])$
Let $L^1 ([0,1])$ be the space of integrable functions on the interval $[0,1]$
Since:

Bernstein’s Proof:If F(x) is any continuous function in the interval C[0,1], it is always possible, regardless how small ε, to determine a polynomial $E_n(x) = {a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n}$ of degree n high enough such that we have ${|F(x) - E_n(x)|} < \varepsilon$ for every point in the interval under consideration.
How can the same proof be used for $L^1 ([0,1])$ instead of $C ([0,1])$?
Can you help by citing a source of proof for $L^1 ([0,1])$?

Functions in $L^1[0,1]$ can be approximated by continuous functions with respect to $L^1$ norm. You cannot approximate $L^1$ function directly by the Bernstein polynomials as for $f\in L^1$ the values  $f(k/n)$ are not well defined.
